# Linear functional $f$ is continuous at $x_0=0$ if and only if $f$ is continuous $\forall x\in X$?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be a linear functional on a normed space $(X, \|\cdot\|)$. Prove that $f$ is continuous at $x_0=0$ if and only if $f$ is continuous at every $x\in X$.

I understand that the $\Leftarrow$ is trivial but what about the other way?

Comment: Continuity means that for each sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $x$ the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$. Now note that this is equivalent to: If $(x_n-x)$ converges to 0, then $f(x_n)-f(x)=f(x_n-x)$ converges to 0.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f$ is continuous at some $x_0\in X$ and let $x_n\to x^*$, for some $x^*\in X$. Then the sequence $x_n-x^*+x_0\to x_0$ and thus $\|f(x_n)-f(x^*)\|=\|f(x_n-x^*+x_0)-f(x_0)\|\to 0$. Hence $f$ is continuous at $x^*$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

$$\lVert T(x-x_0)\rVert=\lVert T(x)-T(x_0)\rVert$$

So if $\lVert x-x_0\rVert<\delta$ we have that $\lVert T(x)-T(x_0)\rVert=\lVert T(x-x_0)\rVert<\epsilon$ by continuity at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

if $f$ be linear function on a normed space $(X,\| \cdot\|)$ then these conditions are equivalent.

$(1)$ : $\|f\| < \infty  $

$(2)$ : $f$ is uniformly continuous

$(3)$ :  $f$ is continuous

$(4)$ : $f$ is  continuous in $0$

$(1)$ $\to$  $(2)$ : $\forall x,y \in X$ and $\forall \epsilon> 0 $  $\|f(x)-f(y)\|$= $\|f(x-y)\|$ $\leq$ $\|f\|$ $\|x-y\|$,  then if $\delta$ = $\frac{\| \epsilon\|}{\|f\| +1}$ we claim that $f$ is uniformly continuous

$(2)$ $\to$  $(3)$ : obvious

$(3)$ $\to$  $(4)$ : obvious

$(4)$ $\to$  $(1)$ : let $f$ be continuous in $0$. the there exist $\epsilon = 1$ and $\delta > 0$ such that if $\| u \|< \delta$ then $\|f(u)\|< 1$

$\|\frac{x}{\frac{2}{\delta}\|x\|}\|$ < $\delta$ $\longrightarrow$  $\frac{\|f(x)\|}{\|x\|}$= $\frac{\|f(u)\|}{\|u\|}$ < $\frac{1}{\frac{2}{\delta}}$= $\frac{\delta}{2}$ $\longrightarrow$ $\|f\|$ < $\infty$ $\quad$

Answer (score 0):

Proof.

$\implies$ obviously

$\Longleftarrow$

Assume L is continuous at $x_0 \in E$. We define sequence $x_1,x_2,\dotsm \in E$  and for any point $x\in E$  such that $||x_n-x ||\rightarrow 0$.

Since L is linear mapping, we have
$$
||L(x_n-x+x_0-x_0)||=||L(x_n-x+x_0)-L(x_0)||
$$
Since L is continuous at $x_0\in E$, for every sequence converging to $x_0$, the $L$ converges $L(x_0)$. We have 
$$
||L(x_n-x+x_0)-L(x_0)||\rightarrow 0
$$
Q.E.D.