# Show that a linear projection is continuous if it is continuous in 0

Tags: general-topology, limits, continuity, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Here is a perfectly fine answer to the question:
[Linear functional $f$ is continuous at $x_0=0$ if and only if $f$ is continuous $\forall x\in X$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1038712/linear-functional-f-is-continuous-at-x-0-0-if-and-only-if-f-is-continuous)

However, I am in a set and topology course and my professor proved this using sequences.
I am going over the proof and am unsure of one step.

Let X with $\lVert{X}\rVert$ and Y with $\lVert{Y}\rVert$ be normed vector spaces(Over ${\rm I\!R}$). Let T: X -> Y be a linear projection.

Show that if T is continuous in $\overline{0}$ it is continuous*.

Solution:

Let a $\in$ X. Let $x_{n}$ -> a.

$x_{n}$ - a -> $\overline{0}$ $\quad$ Because X is a vector space and $x_{n}$ converges to a.

T($x_{n}$ - a) -> $\overline{0}$ $\quad$ **

T($x_{n}$) - T(a) -> $\overline{0}$ $\quad$ b/c T is a *linear* projection

T($x_{n}$) -> T(a) $\quad$ Which implies T is continuous in a.

*In every point I suppose

** Why is this ok?

Is there some clever rule I'm missing?

/Regards

Answer (score 2):

What your techer used were sequences, not series.

The proof is correct. And it doesn't apply to $T(x)=x+b$ since this is *not* a linear map.

Comment: Whoops, I'll change series to sequence.

I'm not maintining it is incorrect, I'm asking for insight into one step.

You are correct, T(x) = x + b is not a linear map. I'll remove that from the question as well.

Answer (score 2):

First off, recall that a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ over a metric spaces $(X,d), (Y,d')$ is continuous at $a \in X$ if and only if given any sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subseteq X$ convergent to $a$, it holds that

$$
f(a) = f(\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n)
$$

Now, to answer $(*)$, the correct statement is

> Given $T$ a linear operator in a normed space $(E, ||\cdot||)$, T is continuous (that is, at every point, or equivalently, that it holds the previously said) if and only if it is continuous at $0$.

Regarding $(**)$, this is because since $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $a$, $(x_n - a)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to zero because, trivially,

$$
||x_n - a|| = ||(x_n - a) - 0||
$$

Now, by continuity and using the characterization that I've previously stated, $T(x_n -a)$ converges to zero because $T$ is continuous at zero, and by linearity, this is the same as $T(x_n) - T(a)$ converging to zero, so

$$
T(a) = \lim_{n \to \infty} T(x_n)
$$

and again by the characterization of continuity that we have, this implies that $T$ is continuous at $a$.

Comment: > Now, to answer (∗), the correct statement is
(*) was not a question, It's my understanding of the following statement "T is continuous". What I am posting is the "only if " part of the proof: "T is continuous if and only if T is continuous in 0"

Comment: Yes, that I've understood, although maybe I did not understand what you meant in $(*)$ then. My point is that in fact, as you say, *continuous* without further clarification means continuous in every point. Just for the sake of completeness, I added the whole statement.